# Updating the displayed contents of a Listbox as a separate list's contents change?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Currently, I have this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


class MainGUI(Frame):

    chapters = []

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        #refresh function contents here
        self.chapters.append("hi")
        #
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Latest Chapters")
        self.style = Style()
        #self.style.theme_use("default")

        scrollbar = Scrollbar(self)
        scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)

        listbox = Listbox(self, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

        for newChapter in self.chapters:
            listbox.insert(END, newChapter)

        listbox.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
        scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

        frame = Frame(self, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1)
        frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        closeButton = Button(self, text="Close", command=self.master.destroy)
        closeButton.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)
        refreshButton = Button(self, text="Refresh Now", command=self.refresh)
        refreshButton.pack(side=RIGHT)

    def refresh(self):
        self.chapters.append("hi")
        #print("Refresh")
        #refresh func here
        self.initUI()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x207+300+300")
    app = MainGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Clicking my refresh button has the `chapters` array appended with an additional item. The `chapters` array is initialized and displayed as a `Listbox` in `initUI()`. When I click the <kbd>refresh</kbd> button, I would like to have the changes to the `chapters` array also shown in the GUI window. I'm not sure what to do - so far I've tried calling `self.initUI()` again but it just makes multiple smaller frames. All help is appreciated!

Comment: You first need to hold the variable `listbox` in your class, just add a `self` to it, then split the relevant part of `initUI()` in your `refresh()` method (mostly the for/loop)

Comment: @PRMoureu thanks! that worked! Basically destroyed everything and rebuilt it in the refresh function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by making the `Listbox` an attribute of the `MainGUI` instance so you can easily reference it in the `refresh()` method. Once that is done, it's a simple matter to add new items to both the `chapters` list *and* the `Listbox` instance:

Here's what I mean:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


class MainGUI(Frame):
    chapters = []

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        #refresh function contents here
        self.chapters.append("hi")
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Latest Chapters")
        self.style = Style()
        #self.style.theme_use("default")
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(self)
        scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)

        self.listbox = Listbox(self, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

        for newChapter in self.chapters:
            self.listbox.insert(END, newChapter)

        self.listbox.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
        scrollbar.config(command=self.listbox.yview)

        frame = Frame(self, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1)
        frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        closeButton = Button(self, text="Close", command=self.master.destroy)
        closeButton.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)
        refreshButton = Button(self, text="Refresh Now", command=self.refresh)
        refreshButton.pack(side=RIGHT)

    def refresh(self):
        self.chapters.append("hi2")  # add string to list
        self.listbox.insert(END, self.chapters[-1])  # update Listbox

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x207+300+300")
    app = MainGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here's what it would look like after clicking the <kbd>Refresh Now</kbd> button a few times.

[image: screenshot of results]

Comment: you might want to mention that you don't have to use a `StringVar` -- you can delete the contents of a listbox without it.

Comment: @Bryan: Good point. Of course, for just adding items, it's not necessary to delete any of the previous contents of the `Listbox`—just make sure it's added to the end of both of them. I've modified my answer accordingly. To bad tkinter doesn't have something like a `ListVar` which would make having to effectively maintain two lists unnecessary.